# UILabel TextColor Not Changing On iphone

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I am changing a `UILabels` text color too the given code below, but it is not working.

```
    Q1.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:88/255.0 green:89/255.0 blue:91/255.0 alpha:0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Q1.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(88/255.f) green:(89/255.f) blue:(91/255.f) alpha:1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably wanted the alpha to be equal to 1 instead of 0 (zero means fully transparent, you might have misunderstood this...):

```
Q1.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:88 / 255.0f
                               green:89 / 255.0f
                                blue:91 / 255.0f
                               alpha:1.0f];
```

By the way, the title of your question is inaccurate. The text color is most probably changing, but you don't see the text since it's transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Besides providing alpha value 0.0, Check for integer division vs float division as the method needs floats, so when you are dividing 88 (int) by a 255.0 (float) you are providing 0 instead of 0.34 for red value and similarly for green and blue.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [Q1 setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:88.0/255.0 green:89.0/255.0 blue:91.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

You just forget to add `alpha:1.0` :)

Comment: Nope. Int 0 is promoted to float 0.0 when needed and possible. Here it's needed and possible.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make it transparent? You should try alpha 1.

```
Q1.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:88/255.0 green:89/255.0 blue:91/255.0 alpha:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this as your color alpha is 0 means transparent

```
   Q1.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:88.0/255.0 green:89.0/255.0 blue:91.0/255.0 alpha:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change alpha to 1, Alpha represents opacity ( transparency).